# How to run instances of dual_annealing in parallel

Tags: python, scipy

Scipy's [dual annealing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.dual_annealing.html) is currently single threaded. However each run starts from a random starting array x0. You can set the x0 yourself as well.  I would like to run 20 instances of dual_annealing in parallel and collect the result from the one with the best result. Here is my current single threaded MWE:

```
from scipy.optimize import dual_annealing
from numpy import exp, sqrt, cos, e, pi
# objective function
def objective(*x):
 x, y = x[0]
 return -20.0 * exp(-0.2 * sqrt(0.5 * (x**2 + y**2))) - exp(0.5 * (cos(2 * pi * x) + cos(2 * pi * y))) + e + 20

# define range for input
r_min, r_max = -5.0, 5.0


# define the bounds on the search
bounds = [[r_min, r_max], [r_min, r_max]]


# perform the simulated annealing search
result = dual_annealing(objective, bounds, maxiter=10000)
print(result)
```

How can I set off 20 of these in parallel and collect the result of the best one? In my real problem the optimization is very slow and the result depends a lot on the random starting array.